# Counting the number of times a threshold is met or exceeded in a multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, percentage

I have an numpy array that I brought in from a netCDF file with the shape (930, 360, 720) where it is organized as (time, latitudes, longitudes).

At each lat/lon pair for each of the 930 time stamps, I need to count the number of times that the value meets or exceeds a threshold "x" (such as 0.2 or 0.5 etc.) and ultimately calculate the percentage that the threshold was exceeded at each point, then output the results so they can be plotted later on.

I have attempted numerous methods but here is my most recent:

```
lat_length = len(lats) 

#where lats has been defined earlier when unpacked from the netCDF dataset

lon_length = len(lons) 

#just as lats; also these were defined before using np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

for i in range(0, lat_length):
     for j in range(0, lon_length):
          if ice[:,i,j] >= x:
               #code to count number of occurrences here
               #code to calculate percentage here
               percent_ice[i,j] += count / len(time) #calculation 

 #then go on to plot percent_ice
```

I hope this makes sense! I would greatly appreciate any help. I'm self taught in Python so I may be missing something simple.

Would this be a time to use the any() function? What would be the most efficient way to count the number of times the threshold was exceeded and then calculate the percentage?

Comment: Are you looking to count the total number of times that the threshold is exceeded in the entire array or the total number of times for each time stamp. i.e are you looking for a single number like 100 times or 930 numbers, so it was exceeded 5 times on time stamp 1 and 10 times on time stamp 2 and so on.

Comment: The total number of times at each lat/lon (hence the i and j pair within the loops), so the final output would result in an array of shape (720, 360) and each point would hold the number of times exceeded. Does that help to clarify it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the input 3D array with the threshold `x` and then sum along the first axis with [`ndarray.sum(axis=0)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) to get the count and thereby the percentages, like so -

```
# Calculate count after thresholding with x and summing along first axis
count = (ice > x).sum(axis=0)

# Get percentages (ratios) by dividing with first axis length
percent_ice = np.true_divide(count,ice.shape[0])
```

Comment: Your answer made me realize how badly I overthought that problem.

Comment: @Vorticity Ah don't worry! Happens to the best of us! :)

Answer (score 3):

Ah, look, another meteorologist!

There are probably multiple ways to do this and my solution is unlikely to be the fastest since it uses numpy's `MaskedArray`, which is known to be slow, but this should work:

Numpy has a data type called a `MaskedArray` which actually contains two normal `numpy` arrays.  It contains a data array as well as a boolean mask.  I would first mask all data that are greater than or equal to my threshold (use `np.ma.masked_greater()` for just greater than):

```
ice = np.ma.masked_greater_equal(ice)
```

You can then use `ice.count()` to determine how many values are below your threshold for each lat/lon point by specifying that you want to count along a specific axis:

```
n_good = ice.count(axis=0)
```

This should return a 2-dimensional array containing the number of good points.  You can then calculate the number of bad by subtracting `n_good` from `ice.shape[0]`:

```
n_bad = ice.shape[0] - n_good
```

and calculate the percentage that are bad using:

```
perc_bad = n_bad/float(ice.shape[0])
```

There are plenty of ways to do this without using `MaskedArray`.  This is just the easy way that comes to mind for me.